# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars issue

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Python script:

```
import math
import numpy as np

scores = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]
y = [0,0,0]
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
sum = 0

def myFunc(x):
    global sum
    global i
    global j

    if not y:
        for s in scores:
            y[i] = 0.5 * scores[i] + 0.2
            i = i+1

    if sum == 0:
        for s2 in scores:
            sum = sum + math.exp(y[j])
            j = j+1

    print sum    
    return math.exp(x)/sum

for s3 in scores:
    print(myFunc(scores[k]))
    k = k+1
```

I have two issues here:

- I'm not getting the expected output for `sum`, which makes the total result wrong
- When I run the script, I get the following output:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myFunc.py", line 40, in <module>
  plt.plot(x, myFunc(scores).T, linewidth=2)
  File "myFunc.py", line 30, in myFunc
  return math.exp(x)/sum
  TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
  ```

Omitting the number values at the beginning, why am I getting this error? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You have three for loops.  Which is causing your problem?  Line 40 with `plt.plot` doesn't exist.  Please cut this down to a [mcve].  This is humongously non-Pythonic, but I'm having trouble figuring out what you're wanting to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def func(scores):
    y = 0.5 * scores + 0.2
    return scores / np.sum(np.exp(y))

scores = np.array([3.0, 1.0, 0.2])

for res in func(scores):
    print(res)
```

Output:

```
0.339460254992
0.113153418331
0.0226306836661
```

Now you can also plot it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(func(scores).T, linewidth=2)
```

[image]